# Getting Mongo results from one month ago

Tags: mongodb

I have around 30-40 records like the example before in my database and I'm looking to get the notifications that are less than 1 month old (from today's date). Is there a way in Mongo to get these results without having to pass in a today's date via JavaScript? Or if I do have to pass it in via JavaScript, how would I process this against my created date?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("48445b4dc72153e9ad7f3bfb"),
    "notificationID" : "78723asd5-vnbb-xv31-afe0-fa9asf164e4",
    "notification" : "Notification #1",
    "created" : ISODate("2016-11-21T20:33:53.695Z")
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MongoDB has its own Javascript interpreter so, unless your MongoDB server has a different date than your system, it knows the current date so you easily use simple Javascript to compute the value you're looking for using  a regular Date object and use it in your query.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1); //1 month ago
db.data.find({created:{$gte:d}}); //change "data" for your collection's name
```

If you need a different date than your database's, I'm afraid you'll have to somehow pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const now = new Date()
    const temp = new Date(now).setMonth(now.getMonth() - 6);
    const priorSix = new Date(temp)

    Table.find({"date" : {$gte: priorSix, $lt: new Date()}}, (err, tables) => {
        if(err) throw new Error(err)
        
        res.status(200).json(tables)
    }).populate('foodList.item')
```

This code worked for me. It retrieves documents of the last 6 month :)